# Will this hash function collide unusually frequently?

Tags: c#, hash, hash-collision, hash-code-uniqueness

I had the following code to generate a hash of an object:

```
public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
{
   return (obj.Prop1.GetHashCode() + obj.Prop2.GetHashCode() + obj.Prop3.GetHashCode()).GetHashCode();
}
```

I.e. I add all the properties' hash codes and then take the hash of this.

In review, a coworker suggested that this will collide too frequently. I'm not sure that this is true because:

1. Given that hash codes are chosen with equal frequency among positive and negative numbers and they wrap around, I don't think there's any additional information we gain about the likelihood of these numbers' sum as opposed to the numbers themselves
2. To the extent that their sum is non-random, hash codes are designed to make numbers that are "close together" become "far apart", so feeding a non-uniformly-distributed value into the function shouldn't be an issue

Who is correct?

It is in C#, in case the answer is language-specific.

Comment: What was your coworker's reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Just suppose Prop1, Prop2 etc are of type `int`. Usually only the lower range of integers is used. Your sum approach will collide more often than necessary.

The HasCode of `7` is 7, which makes perfect sense when hashing `int` by it self. But with your code the tuples `<7, 3>`, `<3, 7>` and `<8, 2>` will all have the same Hash. The same with simple XOR instead of Addition.

The common approach is to add some (prime) numbers and shifting:

```
public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
{
  int hash = 0;
  unchecked
  {         
     hash += 19 * obj.Prop1.GetHashCode();
     hash += 31 * obj.Prop2.GetHashCode();
     hash += 37 * obj.Prop3.GetHashCode();
  }
  return hash;
}
```

The numbers 19, 31, 37 are not too critical. And if you prefer you can use OR or XOR instead of `+` .

Comment: Prime numbers are good and are preferable to shifting, since a simple binning algorithm may well just take the lower N bits of the HashCode; if the properties are shifted, they may end up completely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

[XORing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) would be better:

```
public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
{
   return obj.Prop1.GetHashCode() ^ 
          obj.Prop2.GetHashCode() ^ 
          obj.Prop3.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: See Henk Holterman's reasoning. Mixing with shifts should provide better distribution if GetHashCode for some of the properties does not use whole range...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified FNV HashCode generator, a very similar question has been answered (by me) 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912340/c-hashcode-builder/6486778#6486778)